# Chrome manifest "run_at": "document_end" not working when navigating

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest

I have the following manifest to run on every page load.
The problem is that it is running only when refreshing the page.
The `myscript.js` will not work when I click on a link and navigate, again, only on refresh.
Why is that?
Thanks

```
{
  "name": "BrowserActionExtension",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "That's the tool tip",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ],
      "js": [ "myscript.js" ],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "<all_urls>"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the page contains frames and the link on which you click does not belong to the top frame you get this behaviour.

Take a look to [all_frames](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)

This value is always false, but if you set this to true the script is injected in all frames.